# How can I prevent the mousemove event from working as click in touch devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, onmousemove

I have some jquery code that looks kinda like this.

```
$(".bf4").each(function() {
    $(this).mousemove(function(e) {
        //some code
    });
    $(this).click(function(e) {
        //different code
    });
});
```

The `mousemove` event is for laptops and the `click` for cellphones. Separately these events work fine. But when I use them together (like in the code above), the code that is inside the `mousemove` event gets executed in cellphones and other touch devides instead of the code inside the `click`

I removed the `click` part of the code and tested it again in touch devices like below.

```
$(".bf4").each(function() {
    $(this).mousemove(function(e) {
        //some code
    });
});
```

It still works as `click` in touch devices.

Long story short *"The mousemove event, works like the click event in touch devices, instead of simply not working"*

I have tested this code using touch simulation in both firefox and chrome. I have also tested the code directly on my cellphone. Same result everywhere.

Now since I need to make something **DIFFERENT** happen in cellphones, than in laptops, I need to know why this is happening and how can I prevent it.

Any ideas?

Comment: If on mobile, both `mousemove` and `click` are fired, and on pc only `mousemove`: Make the `click` event cancel the `mousemove` event. This should fix the issue

Answer (score -2):

Wrapup the function in an if statement that will prevent it from working on small devices, something like:

```
   if ($(window).width() > 768) {
      // your mouse events here
   }
```

Comment: While this would theoratically work, I would not recommend it. When someone uses the browser on pc in split screen (or any other way that makes the window smaller in width), the user could get unwanted results.

Comment: @KerwinSneijders, I agree I found a different solution

Comment: @WebMarie I appreciate your effort, don't have enough rep to upvote though so if someone else could do it for me please

Comment: hey @muhammad-usman, any answer you can share? thanks~